# Creating snapshot reports when subreports require parameters?

Tags: reporting-services

My situation is this - I'm using SSRS to create a "cascading" report set. The top-level report pulls all of the data from a table that capture our deployment/release activity. This data includes the property that executed a release, the organization to which that property belongs, the scheduled and actual start and end times of the release (and its constituent deployments), etc., etc., etc., and in the report I aggregate the data by time windows (Fiscal Year, then Quarter, then Month). So, at the top level, the user sees a report that shows how many deployments and releases we executed, how long they were expected to take, and how long they actually took, over the last twelve months, grouped, again, by Fiscal Year, then Quarter, than Month.

Now, the next level of detail the user wants to see is for a given month. When he or she clicks on the link to run that particular sub-report, they now get the same information (number of deployment, number of releases, scheduled and actual durations, etc.) grouped by organization, for that particular month.

Here's my dilemma - the initial report takes a LONG time to render. I would like to create snapshot report to reduce this render time, but my sub-report uses the Month from the top-level report as a parameter. In other words, when I click on the link to the sub-report, the Action setting in SSRS says to use the Month that I clicked on as a parameter to generate the sub-report, and the query in the sub-report filters off of that parameter with the following query condition:

AND FiscalQuarter IN (@Quarter)

So, the reporting works fine, but I am wondering - is there some way that I can get ALL of the data, for ALL quarters, into the sub-report in a snapshot report, and then just generate that snapshot but filtered out for the quarter value that I pass from the top-level report as a parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "*filtered out* for the quarter value"? Do you want to generate multiple snapshots of the subreport for a set of different parameter values?

Comment: Also, I think folks don't mind a bit longer question, if the text is relevant. I think you can safely edit out the first, and last two paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Filtered out may not have been the best terminology. Essentially, at the top level report, results are grouped by fiscal quarter and then again by month, so it's something like:

FQ1
==> July
==> August
==> September

If a user clicks on one of the months, I then want to take him or her to the totals for that month (which some additional detail). Currently I do that by passing parameters of the Fiscal Quarter and the Month for which the user selected a sub-report. But, my filter is actually in the sub-report query, which prevents me from being able to create MHTML reports.

Comment: And I still don't think I answered your question. What I'm trying to ask is, is there a way to create a sub-report that uses a data source that captures ALL data, but that only displays the results that match parameters passed to it from the top-level? Currently my sub-report query takes the QUARTER and MONTH values as query parameters before it actually runs the query. If I could run the query first, create a snapshot report, and THEN use the parameters from the top level report to select which data to display in the sub-report, that would be my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can, by creating a snapshot for sub report for all values.
and the parameter defined on the subreport should be a dataset filter not a query parameter .

Now when you pass parameter from main report to subreport , it will filter it accordingly on the sub report snapshot without having to execute the costly sql

Comment: Azhar, thanks. This also answered my question correctly - I ended up creating additional tables in the report, and inserting them into blank rows. I then toggled the visibility of those rows using the values in the higher level report, and passed the filters in the Action settings.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, reporting services does not provide what you need. [Caching reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) will create a cached version of the report per distinct combination of parameter values, and a similar situation holds for [cached datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx).

You have roughly two options left it seems:

1. Use a cached dataset, have the subreport use the cached dataset but only use the parameter to filter the data once it's retrieved (e.g. in a tablix)
2. Resort to a more database-oriented caching-like or performance enhancing strategy such as for example indexed views for your queries

Comment: Thanks very much Jeroen. Just so I'm clear, what you're saying is that if I'm using month as a parameter, I'd have to create 12 cached sub-reports, one for each month, correct?

Comment: Aye, unless you use one of the workarounds that's true AFAIK.